# JQ to filter only vaule of id

Tags: jq

the following is the JSON data. need to get only of id key

```json
      {apps:[ {
      "id": "/application1/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd",
      "cmd": null,
      "args": null,
      "user": null,
      "env": {},
      "constraints": [
        [
          "hostname",
          "GROUP_BY",
          "5"
        ]
      },
      {
      "id": "/application2/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd",
      "cmd": null,
      "args": null,
      "user": null,
      "env": {},
      "constraints": [
        [
          "hostname",
          "GROUP_BY",
          "5"
        ]
      ]},
```

output expected is

```
/application1/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd
/application2/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a free to use  coding service.

Comment: [jquery] and [jq] are very different things - as [jq] is in your title, was [jquery] a mistake?  Especially as [javascript] is not tagged, and this would be a javascript solution, not jquery.

Comment: Also Please note that your `constraints` is not correct. It has 2 `[` but only 1 `]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing the errors in your JSON, we can use the following [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) filter to get the desired output:

```
.apps[] | .id
```

[JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iwE3rCui3a)

---

Result `jq -r '.apps[] | .id'`:

```
/application1/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd
/application2/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd
```

Comment: Thank you Ostone.. this helped me to solve my need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` to create an array from the properties of the objects. Try this:

```js
let data = {apps:[{"id":"/application1/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd","cmd":null,"args":null,"user":null,"env":{},"constraints":["hostname","GROUP_BY","5"]},{"id":"/application2/4b693882-ffba-4c93-a0f2-cccafcb4d7dd","cmd":null,"args":null,"user":null,"env":{},"constraints":["hostname","GROUP_BY","5"]}]}

let ids = data.apps.map(o => o.id);
console.log(ids);
```

Note that I corrected the invalid brace/bracket combinations in the data structure you posted in the question. I assume this is just a typo in that example, otherwise there would be parsing errors in the console.